# Hibernate: same code on different db

Tags: sql-server, oracle, hibernate

I've done my first little "hello world" with hibernate, inserting some data in my SQLServer db. Now I'm trying to switch db without change the annotation on my domain classes, and I'm having problems.
I've tried to use a behaviour that let the handling of the id on the db, using an identity column on sql server and a sequence with a trigger on oracle (and i was thinking to do the same with postgres), so i declared in my class

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public long getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

this work well on SQLServer, but it give me this error on Oracle:

```
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:132)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:105)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:112)
... 11 more
```

note that also with strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE i got the same error

I was wondering: is there any way to do what i'm trying?

---

Sorry, i posted the wrong stackTrace, the correct one is:

```
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:132)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:105)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:112)
... 11 more
```

note that also with strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE i got the same error

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that hibernate is attempting to use `IDENTITY` generation when you use `AUTO`. Try using `SEQUENCE` generation for Oracle9i. [Here's an example given in JBoss documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-mapping-identifier.html).

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(
    name="SEQ_STORE",
    sequenceName="my_sequence"
)
public class Store implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_STORE")
    public Long getId() { return id; }
}
```

[Take a look at this page for documented list of supported generation types on different DB dialects.](http://www.nightprogrammer.org/development/hibernate-generationtype-auto-dialect-default-overview/)

Comment: sorry, i was trying to change the GenerationType value and posted the wrong stackTrace, the correct error message is different..

Comment: Take a look at update answer. Modify your original question instead of adding an update as an answer.